# UTF8.GetString ошибка компиляции: не удается преобразовать из "byte*" в "byte[]"

Tags: c#, .net

```
byte* pByte = (byte*)ptr.ToPointer();
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pByte);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить?
NetFramework v4.5.2

Comment: Если вы покамест ещё не очень хорошо разбираетесь в C#, я бы настоятельно рекомендовал не использовать unsafe-код, потому что он предполагает **очень** хорошее знание языка, до тонкостей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Encoding.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx) с одним аргументом принимает тип `byte[]`, а не `byte*` о чем и говорит ошибка.

Чтобы передать указатель, используйте метод с двумя аргументами [`Encoding.GetString(Byte*, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823314(v=vs.110).aspx), для этого потребуется передать количество байтов для преобразования.

Также можно преобразовать указатель в массив байтов с помощью [`Marshal.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx), но для этого также нужно знать количество байтов.